# Android Unfortunately App has Stopped

Tags: android

I am getting error : Unfortunately App has Stopped

By using below code, i am trying to call RestaurantActivity by using click on Restaurant Button.

AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:

```
public class AndroidDashboardDesignActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_layout);

        /**
         * Creating all buttons instances
         * */
        // Dashboard News feed button
        Button btn_restaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_news_feed);

        // Dashboard Friends button
        Button btn_friends = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_friends);

        // Dashboard Messages button
        Button btn_messages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_messages);

        // Dashboard Places button
        Button btn_places = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_places);

        // Dashboard Events button
        Button btn_events = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_events);

        // Dashboard Photos button
        Button btn_photos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_photos);

        /**
         * Handling all button click events
         * */

        // Listening to News Feed button click
        btn_restaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching Near Restaurant Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.this, com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.RestaurantActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Listening Friends button click
    btn_friends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.this, com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.FriendsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Listening Messages button click
    btn_messages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.this, com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MessagesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Listening to Places button click
    btn_places.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.this, com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.PlacesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Listening to Events button click
    btn_events.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.this, com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.EventsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Listening to Photos button click
    btn_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.this, com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.PhotosActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

DashboardLayout.java:

```
   package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;



 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 /**
 * Custom layout that arranges children in a grid-like manner, 
 optimizing for even    horizontal and
 * vertical whitespace.
 */
public class DashboardLayout extends ViewGroup {

private static final int UNEVEN_GRID_PENALTY_MULTIPLIER = 10;

private int mMaxChildWidth = 0;
private int mMaxChildHeight = 0;

public DashboardLayout(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public DashboardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, 0);
}

public DashboardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    mMaxChildWidth = 0;
    mMaxChildHeight = 0;

    // Measure once to find the maximum child size.

    int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);

        mMaxChildWidth = Math.max(mMaxChildWidth, child.getMeasuredWidth());
        mMaxChildHeight = Math.max(mMaxChildHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight());
    }

    // Measure again for each child to be exactly the same size.

    childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            mMaxChildWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            mMaxChildHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(
            resolveSize(mMaxChildWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
            resolveSize(mMaxChildHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int width = r - l;
    int height = b - t;

    final int count = getChildCount();

    // Calculate the number of visible children.
    int visibleCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }
        ++visibleCount;
    }

    if (visibleCount == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Calculate what number of rows and columns will optimize for even horizontal and
    // vertical whitespace between items. Start with a 1 x N grid, then try 2 x N, and so on.
    int bestSpaceDifference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int spaceDifference;

    // Horizontal and vertical space between items
    int hSpace = 0;
    int vSpace = 0;

    int cols = 1;
    int rows;

    while (true) {
        rows = (visibleCount - 1) / cols + 1;

        hSpace = ((width - mMaxChildWidth * cols) / (cols + 1));
        vSpace = ((height - mMaxChildHeight * rows) / (rows + 1));

        spaceDifference = Math.abs(vSpace - hSpace);
        if (rows * cols != visibleCount) {
            spaceDifference *= UNEVEN_GRID_PENALTY_MULTIPLIER;
        }

        if (spaceDifference < bestSpaceDifference) {
            // Found a better whitespace squareness/ratio
            bestSpaceDifference = spaceDifference;

            // If we found a better whitespace squareness and there's only 1 row, this is
            // the best we can do.
            if (rows == 1) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            // This is a worse whitespace ratio, use the previous value of cols and exit.
            --cols;
            rows = (visibleCount - 1) / cols + 1;
            hSpace = ((width - mMaxChildWidth * cols) / (cols + 1));
            vSpace = ((height - mMaxChildHeight * rows) / (rows + 1));
            break;
        }

        ++cols;
    }

    // Lay out children based on calculated best-fit number of rows and cols.

    // If we chose a layout that has negative horizontal or vertical space, force it to zero.
    hSpace = Math.max(0, hSpace);
    vSpace = Math.max(0, vSpace);

    // Re-use width/height variables to be child width/height.
    width = (width - hSpace * (cols + 1)) / cols;
    height = (height - vSpace * (rows + 1)) / rows;

    int left, top;
    int col, row;
    int visibleIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }

        row = visibleIndex / cols;
        col = visibleIndex % cols;

        left = hSpace * (col + 1) + width * col;
        top = vSpace * (row + 1) + height * row;

        child.layout(left, top,
                (hSpace == 0 && col == cols - 1) ? r : (left + width),
                (vSpace == 0 && row == rows - 1) ? b : (top + height));
        ++visibleIndex;
    }
}
}
```

RestaurantActivity.java:

```
    public class RestaurantActivity extends Activity {

// flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Google Places
GooglePlaces googlePlaces;

// Places List
PlacesList nearPlaces;

// GPS Location
GPSTracker gps;

// Button
Button btnShowOnMap;

// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Places Listview
ListView lv;

// ListItems data
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


// KEY Strings
public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference"; // id of the place
public static String KEY_NAME = "name"; // name of the place
public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vicinity"; // Place area name

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.restaurants);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    if (!isInternetPresent) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // creating GPS Class object
    gps = new GPSTracker(this);

    // check if GPS location can get
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        Log.d("Your Location", "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude() + ", longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
    } else {
        // Can't get user's current location
        alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "GPS Status",
                "Couldn't get location information. Please enable GPS",
                false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Getting listview
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // button show on map
    btnShowOnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_map);

    // calling background Async task to load Google Places
    // After getting places from Google all the data is shown in listview
    new LoadPlaces().execute();

    /** Button click event for shown on map */
    btnShowOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PlacesMapActivity.class);
            // Sending user current geo location
            i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
            i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

            // passing near places to map activity
            i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
            // staring activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    /**
     * ListItem click event
     * On selecting a listitem SinglePlaceActivity is launched
     * */
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String reference = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reference)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SinglePlaceActivity.class);

            // Sending place refrence id to single place activity
            // place refrence id used to get "Place full details"
            in.putExtra(KEY_REFERENCE, reference);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load Google places
 * */
class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RestaurantActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places..."));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        try {
            // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
            // If you want all types places make it as null
            // Check list of types supported by google
            // 
            String types = "cafe|restaurant"; // Listing places only cafes, restaurants

            // Radius in meters - increase this value if you don't find any places
            double radius = 1000; // 1000 meters 

            // get nearest places
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
                    gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * and show the data in UI
     * Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI from background
     * thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                 * */
                // Get json response status
                String status = nearPlaces.status;

                // Check for all possible status
                if(status.equals("OK")){
                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                        // loop through each place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                            // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                            // Place name
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                            // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                            placesListItems.add(map);
                        }
                        // list adapter
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(RestaurantActivity.this, placesListItems,
                                R.layout.list_item,
                                new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                                        R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                        // Adding data into listview
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
                else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                    // Zero results found
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "Near Places",
                            "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                            false);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RestaurantActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured.",
                            false);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- MainActivity -->
    <activity android:name="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.RestaurantActivity" android:label="Nearest Places">
    </activity>

    <!-- SinglePlaceActivity -->
    <activity android:name="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.SinglePlaceActivity" android:label="Place Details">
    </activity>

    <!-- PlacesMapActivity -->
    <activity android:name="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.PlacesMapActivity" android:label="Near Places Map View">
    </activity>
```

Logcat Says:

```
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps/com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.androidhive.dashboard.DashboardLayout
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.androidhive.dashboard.DashboardLayout
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.onCreate(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:15)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  ... 11 more
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.androidhive.dashboard.DashboardLayout" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps-1.apk
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-31 17:42:17.352: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  ... 22 more
```

Comment: Please use a generic title. Which line causes the error. Also post the code of restaurentActivity.

Comment: problem is `Error inflating class com.androidhive.dashboard.DashboardLayout`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K how can i resolve this?? help me

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj i have posted my RestaurantActivity.java code as well, please check issue....

Comment: restaurentActivity seems ok at the moment. when did the app crash.? on clicking the button or even before it. post the dashboardActivity and Dashboardlayout as well.

Comment: @AmitSuri : u have DashboardLayout class in project ?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj before click on button, not getting Dashboard activity even...and i have posted DashboardLayout Code also...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K yes i have posted that code also please check above..

Comment: @AmitSuri I cant get why and where you have used DashboardLayout class.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj i have downloaded both the codes from Androidhive.info and just trying to call RegisterActivity while click on button, except class name to call i have not changed anything, and what you recommend me to do?

Comment: first check the line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
btn_restaurantFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Launching Near Restaurant Screen
        Intent i = new Intent(AndroidDashBoardDesignActivity.this, RestaurantActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

and change `Manifest.xml` code

```
<activity android:name="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.RestaurantActivity" 
          android:label="Nearest Places">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`AndroidDashBoardDesignActivity.this`

instead of

`getApplicationContext()`.